# Change name of file that's uploaded to GCS from AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have the following code (taken from the sample code) to upload files directly to GCS but it does not preserve the file name  of the original file. Instead it stored using a hash as the filename like

```
'L2FwcGhvc3RpbmdfcHJvZC9ibG9icy9BRW5CMlVxd3BLMk1ZVVg0SVVzSTlUQTMzRzEyVzQ3ZHQtQy1JSjh6ZU5aT0hWc3FzZ2k0NXpfNXZBUTZDRThSQTFNNi0xX0dEY1M4MEFwUFJYbGt4cUkxNkRpeGp6M0VUQS51QlBNM3BJNG9qXy0zVHZF'
```

The problem is that I need to show all the files uploaded to GCS to users so need to preserve the file identity to distinguish the files. They won't be able to identify their uploads from hashes

Here's the sample code... how do I ensure that it uploads with the file name provided? For instance, if I upload a file 'log.csv', it is uploaded as 'log.csv' rather than a hash which doesn't say if it's the file or not.

```
import os
import urllib
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload', gs_bucket_name='uploads')
    self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
    self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url)
    self.response.out.write("""Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit"
        name="submit" value="Submit"> </form></body></html>""")

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
    blob_info = upload_files[0]
    self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())

class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, resource):
    resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
    self.send_blob(blob_info)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),
                               ('/upload', UploadHandler),
                               ('/serve/([^/]+)?', ServeHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filename` and other metadata are in the `BlobInfo` object in the **datastore**, not in the **blobstore** per se.  See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass for all details of the `BlobInfo` class (and https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers for how the provided handlers deal with it on both upload and download).

So, instead of requiring the user to pass you the blob key (so you can use `blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)` directly on the request), you can allow the user to pass you the filename, use `BlobInfo.gql` to give you all the blobinfo objects for the given filename (no guarantee of uniqueness, of course -- unless you enforce it yourself in the app at upload time by rejecting duplicate filenames), then use the `key()` method of those blob info objects to get the required blob keys.

Access to the datastore (for blobs' metadata) is faster than access all the way to the blobstore, so e.g to present a list of uploaded files, `BlobInfo.all()` (returning a query to which you can add filters) will let you present filenames & other metadata (content type, creation datetime, size in bytes) to your users, for them to select which blob(s) they want to retrieve.